R: How to replace values in polygon geometry without a for loop?
I have over 60,000 building polygons footprints in shapefile format (polygonZ) where I need to replace the z values (for each ring) for all the polygon vertices, so that all the Z values for the polygon are the same. The issue is that we have 3D polygons that have not been edited in 3D so some rings have correct Z values for all the vertices while other rings have a few erroneous Z values which need to be corrected.
I am able to do it via a for loop but it takes a good 45 minutes to complete as it needs to iterate through all the polygons.
I was wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to speed this up?
I did try the following, thinking I could replace all the values at once via indexing but it didn't work. I assume its due to there being a different number of vertices per polygon compared to the "new values" I want to use as replacement.
> myshape$geometry[][[1]][[1]][[1]][,2] <- new_values[]

Error in myshape$geometry[][[1]][[1]][[1]][, 2] <- new_values[] : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Here is a working example using stock R data. I am replacing the X instead of Z for this example.
library(sf)
library(tictoc) 

# load test data
myshape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

# recast to polygon (my actual data are polygons, not multipolygons)
myshape <- st_cast(myshape, "POLYGON")

# make some random data
new_values <- runif(nrow(myshape))

# replace some values
tic()
for (row in 1:nrow(myshape)) {
  # replace
  myshape$geometry[row][[1]][[1]][,2] <- new_values[row]
}
toc()

edit: clarified that each ring will have the same Z value, recast to polygons (my actual data are polygons), provided background on my problem and also fixed an error in my for loop.

for (row in nrow(myshape)) will only loop over nrow(myshape), not 1 to nrow(myshape) ! Try 1:nrow(myshape) instead. Otherwise this looks fine (although its modifying X, not Z, but you prob know that...)

Actually this doesn't work for general multipolygon geometries since you are only changing the first ring of a multipolygon geometry. You really need to iterate over all myshape$geometry[row][[1]][[ring]][[part]][, 2] for all values of row, ring and part within features.

Thanks for catching the 1:nrows(myshape)! I edited the original post now and hopefully clarified I need to update all the values for each ring.

There's something going on that maybe someone else can explain--possibly the whole geometry column is being overwritten with every iteration using the for loop. A Map approach is orders of magnitude faster with a larger sf object:
library(sf)

# load test data
myshape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))[sample(100, 1e4, 1),]

# make some random data
new_values <- runif(1e4)
myshape$geometry2 <- myshape$geometry3 <- myshape$geometry

system.time({
  for (row in 1:nrow(myshape)) {
    # replace
    myshape$geometry2[row][[1]][[1]][[1]][,2] <- new_values[row]
  }
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>  105.19    0.39  105.64

system.time({
  f <- function(g, x) {
    g[[1]][[1]][,2] <- x
    g
  }
  
  myshape$geometry3[] <- Map(f, myshape$geometry, new_values)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.07    0.00    0.06

identical(myshape$geometry2, myshape$geometry3)
#> [1] TRUE


Note my comment above about multipolygon geometries applies here. eg check myshape$geometry[4] which only has its Y set for the first ring.

Just following the OPs code. I can update it once the OP confirms the target is not just the first ring.

I tried a simple matrix and the loop was "happy" :   foo <- matrix(nr=100,nc=10000)
floop <- function(x,y) {
for(jrow in 1:nrow(x)) x[jrow,] <- y
return(invisible(x))
}
system.time(floop(foo,1:1e4))
system.time(floop(foo,1:1e4))
user  system elapsed
0.034   0.010   0.042

@jblood94 THANK YOU so much for teaching me about the map() function! My script that took 45 mins to complete is now finished in just 26 seconds as I had some other loops that were doing the same thing. Replaced them with map() and its lightening fast now.

@CarlWitthoft, I suspect is has something to do with the structure of myshape$geometry and how the data are being accessed in the for loop.

@Norrislam, I don't think it is Map per se that is especially fast. A for loop will typically be at least as fast as Map. As I mentioned to @CarlWitthoft, I suspect the poor performance has something to do with the structure of myshape$geometry and how the data are being accessed in the for loop.

@jblood94 thanks for clarifying. not sure why accessing geometry would take that much longer. I will do some testing when I have a chance. thanks for all the help!

This scales relatively well. The repex is based on the nc.shp data, see below for a larger example. The workflow:

Create new_values df with z values and associated feature ID e.g. nc$NAME
st_cast() myshape to polygon, assign pid to individual polygons, st_cast() to points, join XYZ values and create geometry, rebuild multipolygons

library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Load test data
myshape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"))

# Make some random z coordinate data with associated feature ID e.g. myshape$NAME
set.seed(1)
new_values <- data.frame(NAME = myshape$NAME,
                         z = runif(nrow(myshape)))

# Create output with z values assigned
sf_poly <- myshape %>%
  # Split multipolygons and assign unique id to each polygon for 
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  mutate(pid = 1:n(), .by = NAME) %>%
  # Cast to point, retrieve lon/lat values, left_join() z values
  st_cast("POINT") %>%
  mutate(x = st_coordinates(.)[,1],
         y = st_coordinates(.)[,2]) %>%
  left_join(., new_values, by = "NAME") %>%
  # Drop original geometry, create new XYZ geometry, assign CRS
  st_drop_geometry() %>%
  sf_pt(., keep = TRUE) %>%
  rename(geometryz = geometry) %>%
  st_set_crs(st_crs(myshape)) %>%
  # Rebuild multipolygons in two steps, otherwise non-contiguous features will be joined
  summarise(geometryz = st_combine(geometryz), .by = c(NAME, pid)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON") %>%
  summarise(geometryz = st_combine(geometryz), .by = NAME) %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOLYGON")


Result from larger dataset on low-spec PC:
Using this data, with 60,324 polygons:
# Set extent
sfc <- st_sfc(st_polygon(list(rbind(c(0,0), c(20,0), c(20,20), c(0,0)))))

# Make polygon sf
sf_grid <- st_make_grid(sfc, cellsize = .088, square = FALSE) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  mutate(NAME = paste0("poly", sprintf("%02d", 1:n()))) %>%
  st_set_crs(st_crs(myshape)) %>%
  rename(geometry = x)

It took ~4.63 minutes. Not entirely representative, as sf_grid has no multipolygon features, but a decent time reduction nonetheless.

WOW! this is some amazing R wizardry here! It will take me a bit to understand and implement the code for my script.

@Norrislam - I've updated the code with annotations, and removed some unneeded steps.

thanks! I am still new to R and trying to wrap my brain around the dplyr pipeline so great to see a solution using this.
